# Filter products on create sale order lines odoo v11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

There is an approved quotation which contains certain products as line items.

I wish to create sales order with respect to the quotation. While creating order, I have mentioned the approved quotation as reference in order.

Below is the model structure I am working with:

Quotation:

```
quotation = fields.Char('Quotation No')
quote_line = fields.One2many('quotation.line', 'quote_id')
```

Quotation Line:

```
quote_id = fields.Many2one('quotation', string='Quote')
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Products')
```

Order:

```
name = fields.Char(string='Order Reference')
order_line = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'order_id')
x_quotation = fields.Many2one('quotation', string='Quotation')
```

Order Line:

```
order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', string='Order')
o_product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Products')
```

There are more than 50 products in `product.product`. Among them, approved quotation contains 10 products as line items.

In `sale.order.line` when used `Many2one` from `product.product`, it lists all products by default. I want to list only those items which are in approved quotation list.

Thank you in advance.